# Go HTTP Server: Handling Routes with Map

Tags: regex, http, go

I have a `map` in Go with routes (e.g. `/static/stylesheets/main.css`) as keys and the corresponding code as the value (effectively, a giant string). I was just wondering, is there an easy way in Go by which I can create an HTTP server, which always check an incoming request against the `map` and renders the value associated with the matched key, if the key exists?

So far, I have...

```js
func main() {
    var m = generateMap()
    http.handleFunc("/", renderContent);
}

func renderContent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, m[path]); 
}
```

I know this code is far from done, but hopefully it clarifies my objective. How would I pass in the `path` and `m` into `renderContent` as well as how do I have `handleFunc` actually handle regexes (essentially, any path)?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle regexes"? Also, it seems like what you want is essentially [`http.FileServer`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) with a custom [`http.FileSystem`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem).

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a `muxer` or a `router`, of which there are *many* already written.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to not writing it yourself, something small quick and out of the box - look at gorilla mux. Their toolkit lets you choose the components you want, so just add their mux if all you want is routing with regex.

I found it particularly helpful for obtaining variable from routes.

```
r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}", ArticleHandler)
...

vars := mux.Vars(request)
category := vars["category"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your map an [`http.Handler`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler):

```
type httpFiles struct {
    fileMap map[string][]byte
}

func (hf httpFiles) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path
    w.Write(hf.fileMap[path])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend package [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) being the fastest go router around. Go's built-in mux is incomplete and slow without an easy way to capture URL parameters.

Also, you might consider making each route a struct so it's easier to handle when you have several routes.

This code captures URL parameter, compare it to the keyword of the map and print the string of code chunk to the console.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    mux "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    Handle      mux.Handle

}

var codeChunk = map[string]string{ "someUrlPath" : "func printHello(){\n\tfmt.Println(\"Hello\")\n}" }

var route = Route{
    "MyHandler",
    "GET",
    "/:keywordUrl",
    MyHandler,
}

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps mux.Params) {

    // Handle route "/:keywordUrl"
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    // get the parameter from the URL
    path := ps.ByName("keywordUrl")

    for key, value := range codeChunk {
        // Compare the parameter to the key of the map
        if key != "" && path == key {
            // do something
            fmt.Println(value)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    router := mux.New()
    router.Handle(route.Method, route.Pattern, route.Handle)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))

    // browse to http://localhost:8080/someUrlPath to see 
    // the map's string value being printed.
}
```